# How could I increment alphabetic versions using batch script or perl?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a version like `1.0.1A`
I want the version to be incremented on each run like:
`1.0.1B`, `1.0.1C`, `1.0.1D`, ... `1.0.1Z`, `1.0.1AA`, `1.0.1AB`, ... `1.0.1AZ`, `1.0.1BA`, etc.

How can we achieve this?

Right now I am using Perl and the version is like `1.0.0.A`, `1.0.0.B`, etc.

```
my @Splitversion = split(/\./,$Buildno);
my $NEXTBUILDLETTER = ++$Splitversion[3];
$NextBuild = "$Splitversion[0]\.$Splitversion[1]\.$Splitversion[2]\.$NEXTBUILDLETTER";  
print $NextBuild;
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I understand your intention. But, how could you justify that I am looking for whole code. I need some idea and little logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $Buildno = '1.02B';

my ($version,$letters) = $Buildno =~ /^(.*?)([A-Z]+)\z/
    or die "invalid buildno $Buildno\n";
my $NextBuild = $version . ++$letters;
print $NextBuild, "\n";
```

Comment: it works if the version is like 1.0.0.A, 1.0.0.B etc.

But, I want 1.0.1A, 1.0.1B....etc
if i change the code to
`my $NEXTBUILDLETTER = ++$Splitversion[2];`
`$NextBuild = "$Splitversion[0]\.$Splitversion[1]\.$NEXTBUILDLETTER";  `
`print $NextBuild;`
it gives 1.0.2, 1.0.3 etc

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.  Edited my answer

Comment: It always says Invalid Version.
invalid buildno 1.0.2B  at version.pl

Comment: made it a complete script; it works for me.  is your $Buildno maybe really "1.0.2B\n"?  if so, `chomp($Buildno)` first

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your help.
This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "version=10.0.1A"
:next
CALL :incver %version%
ECHO version=%version% - new version=%newver%
SET "xxx="
SET /p xxx=Another ?
IF NOT DEFINED xxx SET "version=%newver%"&GOTO next
GOTO :EOF

:incver
SET "newver=%1"
SET "valid=A B C Y Z"
:: next on final character
CALL :changechar %newver:~-1%
IF %nextchar% neq %valid:~0,1% SET "newver=%newver:~0,-1%%nextchar%"&GOTO :EOF
:: Is 2nd-last a valid char?
:: If so, increment 2nd-last and restart last.
FOR %%b IN (%valid%) DO IF %newver:~-2,1%==%%b (
 CALL :changechar %%b
 CALL SET "newver=%newver:~0,-2%%%nextchar%%%nextchar%"
 GOTO :EOF 
)
:: Not a valid character so append another
SET "newver=%newver:~0,-1%%nextchar%%nextchar%
GOTO :eof

:changechar
SET "nextchar="
FOR %%a IN (%valid% %valid:~0,1%) DO IF DEFINED nextchar (
 SET "nextchar=%%a"
 GOTO :EOF 
) ELSE IF %%a==%1 SET "nextchar=%%a"

GOTO :eof
```

Interesting little exercise.

In the above routine, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for next, any character entry will terminate.

Starting with the initial string, the routine `:incver` will generate `newver` containing the next-in-sequence after the code supplied as `:incver`'s parameter.

The next code is obtained by looking at the last character and selecting the next, incrementing the last valid character results in selecting the first.

So, if the next selected is the same as the first-valid, then we need to make a decision - to append a new character (remove the last and add the first-valid twice) or increment the second-last character, and append the first-valid.

Comment: @Thanks Magoo. 
This is perfect. But, if I change
`:next`
`CALL :incver %version%`
`ECHO version=%version% - new version=%newver%`
to
`SETLOCAL`
`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (Version.txt) do SET "version=%%i"`
`:next`
`CALL :incver %version%`
`ECHO %newver%%LF%>E:\Tests\Version.txt`
why is generating extra empty line in version.txt file.
1)1.0.2O
2)Emptyline
Any suggestions to avoid that line.

Comment: If I try `ECHO| set /p=%newver%%LF%>Version.txt` , it's removing extra line but it's generating space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($version,$letters) = $Buildno =~ /^(.*?)\.([A-Z]+)\z/
or die "invalid buildno $Buildno/n";
$NextBuild = $version . ++$letters;
print $NextBuild."\n";
```

Comment: invalid buildno 1.0.2B . at version.pl line 33